# Show $\lim_n \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}} \chi_{\{f > j/2^n\}}= f$ pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \geq 0$ be a function. Show that

$$\lim_n \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}} \chi_{\{f > j/2^n\}} = f$$ pointwise. Here $\chi_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A$ and $\{f > j/2^n\}:= \{x : f(x) > j/2^n\}$

Attempt:

I'm a bit lost here. The sum looks really complicated and it's hard to see for me what's going on.
I tried to estimate $$|f(x)- \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}} \chi_{\{f > j/2^n\}}(x)|$$
but could not get anything that becomes small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x$, and $n$ sufficiently large, you have
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}} \chi_{\{f(x) > j/2^n\}}(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{2n}} \chi_{\{j<2^nf(x)\}}(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil 2^n f(x) \rceil-1} 1 = \frac{\lceil 2^n f(x) \rceil-1}{2^n}$$

Now you should be able to find the limit.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Writing it like that makes this very easy!

Comment: Hmmm, is it possible that if $2^n f(x)$ is a natural number, then the summation should be $2^n f(x)-1$ instead?

Comment: You are right, I edited, it should work now ! :)

Comment: If you are interested, have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802886/proposition-7-12-folland-strict-inequality