# Proposition 7.12 Folland strict inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading proposition 7.12 in Folland's text on real analysis:

[image]

Why is the marked inequality true? I.e. why is it strict?

Relevant context: LSC function = left semi continuous function, LCH space = locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: It's *lower* semicontinuous, not "left".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition,
$$\phi_n(x)=\frac{r}{2^n}$$
where $r$ is the number of sets $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,2^{2n}\}$ with $2^nf(x)>j$.
If $f(x)=0$ then $\phi_n(x)=0$, otherwise
$$\phi_n(x)=\min(2^n,r/2^n)$$
where $r$ is the greatest integer with $r<2^nf(x)$.
So, unless $f(x)=0$, then
$$\phi_n(x)\le r/2^n<(2^n f(x))/2^n=f(x).$$

But in our case $x\in K_j\subseteq U_{n,j}$ for some $j$, and then
$f(x)>j/2^n$, so $f(x)\ne0$.